# Prove that the nonhomogeneous Neumann problem has a solution only if $\int_Ωf = 0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

Let $Ω ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary $∂Ω$, and denote by $\vec{n}$ the outer unit normal to $∂Ω$. Prove that the nonhomogeneous Neumann problem

$$
\begin{cases}
      ∆u = f & \text{ in }Ω \\
      \langle∇u ,\vec{n}\rangle = 0 & \text{ on }∂Ω \\
\end{cases}
$$

has a solution only if $\int_Ωf = 0$.

How would I go about doing this? Can anyone help to me understand where to start better?

Comment: Necessary condition: by divergence theorem. The Laplacian is the divergence of gradient.

Comment: Also of [existence of the solution of Neumann problem in $ \mathbb{R}^3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/790245) if you are only interested in the necessity part.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to follow and understand it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the correct regularity on $f$, this is an application of the divergence theorem. Indeed notice that $$\int_{\Omega}f\,dx = \int_{\Omega}\Delta u\, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega}\nabla u \cdot n\, d\mathcal{H}^{N-1} = 0,$$
where the last equality follows from the Neumann condition. This is usually referred to as a compatibility condition.

Comment: Could you expand just a bit on that last equality and why it follows from the Neumann condition?

Comment: The Neumann condition says that the integrand in last integral is constant and equal to $0$. (I've used a different notation for the inner product, maybe that caused confusion..)

Comment: Ah ok I can follow that now. Thank you